Cloudflare D1 (SQL Lite) - Bulk Insert?
When I run the following I get:

Error: D1_TYPE_ERROR: Type 'object' not supported

Is there a more appropriate way to do bulk inserts with SQL Lite and Cloudflare's D1 tooling?
const items = [1,2,3,4]

await db
.prepare(`INSERT OR REPLACE INTO table_name (field1, field2) VALUES (?, ?), (?, ?)`)
.bind(items)
.run();


D1Database bind function use spread operator for its parameter.
bind(...values: unknown[]): D1PreparedStatement;

So you can write like this.
const items = [1,2,3,4]

await db
.prepare(`INSERT OR REPLACE INTO table_name (field1, field2) VALUES (?, ?), (?, ?)`)
.bind(...items)
.run();

To help future users, I created a helper class for batch inserts.
Since D1 allows bind parameters with ? keyword, we can dynamically create values like this.
const values = [ ['Foo', 1], ['Bar', 2] ]

const valueTemplate: string = values.map(value =>
    `(${Array(value.length).fill('?').join(', ')})`
).join(', ')   // result = (Foo, 1), (Bar, 2)

const params: unknown[] = values.flat()  // result = ['Foo', 1, 'Bar', 2]

Then, we can batch insert like this.
const query = `INSERT INTO table (col1, col2) VALUES ${valueTemplate};`
const result = await db.prepare(query).bind(...params).run()

It works fine until you exceeds the D1 params limits. Cloudflare limits the params size (Maximum bound parameters per query) to 100. So we have to split values into chunks. My helper class D1Ext will solve that problem.
D1Ext.ts
export class D1Ext {

    // ('Foo', 1, ?) and ['Bar']
    private static getValueTemplateAndParams(previousParamSize: number, row: unknown[]) {
        const values: string[] = []
        const params: unknown[] = []
        let paramLimitReached = false

        for (const value of row) {
            if (value === null) values.push('NULL')
            else if (typeof value === 'number') values.push(String(value))
            else {
                values.push('?')
                params.push(value)
                paramLimitReached = (previousParamSize + params.length) > 100
            }
        }

        return {
            valueTemplate: '(' + values.join(', ') + ')',
            params: params,
            paramLimitReached: paramLimitReached
        }
    }

    public static batchInsert(db: D1Database, table: string, columns: string[], rows: Array<unknown>[]):  Promise<D1Result[]> {
        // INSERT INTO table (col1, col2) VALUES
        const queryPrefix = `INSERT INTO ${table}` + ` (${columns.join(', ')}) VALUES `

        const batches: {query: string, params: unknown[]}[] = []

        // (?, NULL) (NULL, ?)
        let values: string[] = []
        // ['Foo', 'Bar']
        let params: unknown[] = []

        rows.forEach(row => {
            const valueAndParams = this.getValueTemplateAndParams(params.length, row)
            if (valueAndParams.paramLimitReached) {
                // stored as a batch when param limit (100) reached
                const query = queryPrefix + values.join(', ') + ';'
                batches.push({query: query, params: params})

                // prepare for new batch
                values = [valueAndParams.valueTemplate]
                params = [...valueAndParams.params]
            } else {
                values.push(valueAndParams.valueTemplate)
                params.push(...valueAndParams.params)
            }
        })

        if (values.length > 0) {
            // stored as a batch if values is not empty
            const query = queryPrefix + values.join(', ') + ';'
            batches.push({query: query, params: params})
        }

        return db.batch(batches.map(batch => db.prepare(batch.query).bind(...batch.params)))
    }
}

D1Ext class usage
const tableName = 'table1'
const columns = ['col1', 'col2']
const values = [ ['Foo', 1], ['Bar', 2] ]

const results = await D1Ext.batchInsert(db, tableName, columns, values)
const isInserted: boolean = results.filter((result) => result.success).length == results.length


Note that my class skips NULL and number values to reduce the batch (chunk) size. You can remove it in getValueTemplateAndParams function if you want.

